# Slick Nav Menu not working (online)

Tags: slicknav

I'm trying to get Slick Nav working and I'm currently testing it unsuccessfully on an empty page online. Locally it works perfectly, but it just doesn't want to run online - even if its the identical code. I have put the files from the "dist" folder from the slick nav download into a folder called "SlickNav" on my main folder on my FTP-Server (just like I did it locally). My test page contains the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="SlickNav/slicknav.css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="SlickNav/jquery.slicknav.min.js"></script>

// I already tried putting my URL before the link rel and the script src above but it didn't help

<script>
$(function(){
    $('#menu').slicknav({
        label: "MENU"
    });
});
```

```
<ul id="menu">
<li><a class="scroll" href="#features">Features</a></li>
<li><a class="scroll" href="#usage">Usage Instructions</a></li>
<li><a class="scroll" href="#examples">Examples</a></li>
<li><a href="http://github.com">View on Github</a></li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying this for over 3 hours now and I just don't see it anymore.. perhaps someone had similar problems or simply sees the (probably dumb) mistake, I would be eternally grateful..

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution after inspecting the console: For the code 
   `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

which I simply copy and pasted had to be changed to match the https of my site ->     `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>`